# Why does the addition of flourine salts lower the melting point of thorium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I recently read an article on Thorium reactors by John Suchocki (unfortunately, a link would only lead to a paywall). In it, he mentions that in the production of Thorium reactors, "The thorium is first blended with fluoride salts to bring the melting point to
a relatively cool 360°C."
How does this work? Shouldn't adding salts *raise* the melting point of a substance?

Comment: The phase diagrams of ThF3 and simple salts (e.g. LiF) often have deep eutectics on them. Which is why they are used in thorium molten salt reactors.

Comment: Look at the fluorine article in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine and scroll down to the 1529 discovery by Agricola concerning the discovery of that adding calcium fluoride would facilitate the removal of slag (atop the molten steel) by rendering the slag “flowable”. Whence the mineral name for calcium fluoride: fluorite. The mixed oxide fluoride salts melt at lower temperatures than oxides such as the refractory thorium dioxide.

Comment: I presume you are interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLiBe (given your 360C number)? note that is the melting point of a particular Be-Li-F compound without any ThF3 added to the mix.

Comment: [Conceptual Chemistry by John Suchocki Chapter 5: Essay
Safer Fission Reactors](https://conceptualacademy.com/sites/default/files/CC05Essayb.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Farcher - indeed, that is poorly written - you mix the salt ThF3 into the Li2BeF4 mix (which already has the 360C melting point by itself).

Comment: And I really should know that it is ThF4. Sigh. Not enough coffee...